# Headless Raspbian Jessie 8.0 keeps crashing days apart

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, headless, jessie-lite, crash

I leave my raspberry pi on almost all of the time and hardly ever see it crash, but sometimes, maybe every other day or so, I find that I am unable to SSH into my Pi. I go downstairs and see that the green indicator light is no longer flashing, leaving just a solid red.

This has happened many times before and I have already downloaded a fresh IMG file and reflashed the SD card with a fresh install of Jessie, but this keeps happening.

The last entry I can find in the /var/syslog file before the crash is this:

```
Sep 21 08:17:11 nalusis kernel: [   15.540726] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
```

The only other thing I can think of is that perhaps the SD card has gone bad, or worse: the Pi board.

Here is a little before the crash:

```
Sep 21 16:17:06 nalusis systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Sep 21 16:17:06 nalusis systemd[1]: Starting Serial Getty on ttyAMA0...
Sep 21 16:17:06 nalusis systemd[1]: Started Serial Getty on ttyAMA0.
Sep 21 16:17:06 nalusis systemd[1]: Starting Login Prompts.
Sep 21 16:17:06 nalusis systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
Sep 21 16:17:08 nalusis apache2[453]: Starting web server: apache2.
Sep 21 16:17:08 nalusis systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Sep 21 16:17:08 nalusis systemd[1]: Starting Multi-User System.
Sep 21 16:17:08 nalusis systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
Sep 21 16:17:08 nalusis systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
Sep 21 16:17:08 nalusis systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Sep 21 16:17:08 nalusis systemd[1]: Startup finished in 3.133s (kernel) + 8.767s (userspace) = 11.900s.
Sep 21 16:17:09 nalusis ntpd[474]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 fe80::43a9:4f38:d61d:45f4 UDP 123
Sep 21 16:17:09 nalusis ntpd[474]: peers refreshed
Sep 21 16:17:11 nalusis kernel: [   15.237648] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
...
Had to reboot after
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the information in the question is inadequate  You don't even bother to tell us what is running on your Pi and ask us to speculate as to whether there may be a problem or not!

Comment: I can see your hostname now ;) Seriously though, those are pretty normal boot messages, nothing suggesting a crash. Like I said, by the time the kernel crashes it may simply not be safe to write anything to logfile.

Comment: @joan Pi is running nothing but an updated version of apache

Comment: What are you using as a power supply?  The 3 is a bit fussier this way, I think.

Comment: It is either a 2amp or 2.5, can't really remember but it is sufficient nonetheless

Comment: In ordwr to get closer to the reason, connect a tty and wait for the next crash. Take a screenshot with your smartphone.

Answer (score 2):

Given the information provided, it's pretty much impossible to tell what's wrong. There are 3 things I'd suggest, in order:

1. Try flashing a new SD card and running from it.
2. Try running a vanilla system with no extra software installed, and without any extra hardware connected to the board (USB sticks and the like). Perhaps you're doing that already, in which case I have bad news for you: you probably do have a faulty RPi.
3. Kernel panic events often don't go to syslog: writing anything to the filesystem is foolish when the system is about to hang up. I wouldn't trust SSH to get all the messages either. If you really want to know what is happening, you should set up a serial UART connection, add `console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200` to your `/boot/cmdline.txt` and wait for the crash to happen with another computer collecting messages from the UART. Once you get those messages, check them for clues.

In case you come to step 3, even if you get to know what exactly is wrong, there will probably be no fix for it. Modern electronics are designed to be replaced, not repaired.

Answer (score 1):

Not having the green ACT light flashing does not mean anything is wrong, it just means not much is happening, at least in terms of I/O to the SD card, which is what that light literally indicates -- i.e., it's possible for the system to be very busy and there to be no ACT light activity.  It's mostly useful at boot, and for checking that the SD card isn't active if you have to pull the plug, since doing so at that point is more likely to cause corruption.

This is interesting though:

```
Sep 21 08:17:11 REDACTED kernel: [   15.540726] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
```

You actually had me searching though logs to find a similar example of a REDACTED message, lol, until I realized you just meant the hostname.

Anyway, that one's a pretty standard one post boot, and the `15.540726` is a timestamp in seconds since the kernel started counting.

In other words, this is from about 15 seconds after a reboot, and other messages leading up to it should confirm that.  If you didn't trigger this, you should look backward through the log to before the last `0.000000` message (there are a surprising number of things that happen in the first microsecond), which should be a note about the logger starting up, at which point it dumps these cached messages from the kernel (they don't actually appear in the log in the first microsecond, but by 15 s they should be).

Any messages from right before are from before the system shut down and that may include a clue about about what triggered the reboot.  Even if it appears innocuous, anything from 8:10 or 8:15 onward is worth scrutiny.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KTjP3vBu Here is a pastebin

Comment: Not every log message includes a kernel timestamp `[    N.NNNNNN]`, since not every log message is from the kernel.  Those are from the init system during the boot process.  You need to look back up before that to find the messages stamped `[   0.000000]`, which is the big bang of system initialization:  The beginning of the universe, so to speak.  What you need to look at is information from before the big bang, about why the previous universe ended and this one started.

Comment: These are the only things I could see with all zeros http://pastebin.com/Kt8rNg66

Comment: @user4191887 please isolate the crash messages and include them in your question. I don't have access to pastebin, and besides stuff you put there won't last forever.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Of course

Comment: @user4191887 Okay you're still not following my point here:  What you need to look at are messages from *before* the reboot happened.  The on-disk logs are not recreated very time you boot, and they are appended to, so `/var/log/syslog` may contain messages going back many reboot cycles.  **And it would be best if you add them to the question**.  Stuff from a few minutes of logging *prior to*  the last set of `[0.000000]` messages (pay attention, because again, there will be more than one set, so don't look from the beginning, look from the end of the file).

Comment: @goldilocks Is this of any help? This is the logs that appear at the beginning of reboot http://pastebin.com/K2cpLseE

Comment: This means it booted about a hour (16:17) before that that shutdown at 17:30.   Maybe that implies it rebooted *twice* without you doing anything?  It's impossible to say why based on that though.

Comment: @goldilocks No, sorry if it was unclear. 16:17 is the time that it seems to crash, and 17:26 is the time I physically rebooted the Pi

Comment: That still means it rebooted once without you doing anything.  Again: `[   14.658194]` is a kernel timestamp, in seconds, from when the kernel started.  So at 16:17:10, if the kernel has only been running for 14.66 seconds, the system was booted at ~16:16:55 (although since it probably hasn't updated the time via network at that point, it may be inaccurate; you should be able to figure out the difference by looking at the clock+date style timestamps as the boot progresses -- `ntpd` is the service that correct the time).